# Why can't I connect my website to a SQL Server database hosted on another computer via its public ip

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database-connection, connection-string

I have a website hosted on a shared server, and I have setup on server to allow remote connection, and also turned on to allow remote connections.

Also I have turned the firewall off.

I am able to log in to my SQL Server via our static ip and port from a different computer not on our network from SQL Server Management Studio, and also when I run my website on my local host,

But when I publish our website to our hosted server it will not connect to our database and return an error :

> [Win32Exception (0x80004005): An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions][SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.)]

This is our connection string

```
Data Source=000.000.00.00,12341;Integrated Security=False; 
  User ID=myUserNmae;password=myPassword;Initial Catalog=dBaseName;
```

What else could be wrong here?

Comment: ["An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions"](https://www.google.com/search?q=An+attempt+was+made+to+access+a+socket+in+a+way+forbidden+by+its+access+permissions)

Comment: You need to make sure that the communication from the website to the sql server ports are open.

Comment: the ports are open as you could see that im able to log in from management studio from computer on different network

Answer (score 0):

you may have to open the program, not (simply) the port

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646023.aspx

```
To add a program exception to the firewall using the Windows Firewall item in Control Panel.

    On the Exceptions tab of the Windows Firewall item in Control Panel, click Add a program.

    Browse to the location of the instance of SQL Server that you want to allow through the firewall, for example C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.<instance_name>\MSSQL\Binn, select sqlservr.exe, and then click Open.

    Click OK.
```

You'll want to read especially about "Dynamic Ports"

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646023.aspx#BKMK_dynamic_ports

Can you try:

```
Data Source=127.0.0.1,12341;Integrated Security=False; 
  User ID=myUserNmae;password=myPassword;Initial Catalog=dBaseName;
```

Does the machine have an internal and external IP ?  Aka, you may have to use the internal-IP (a real one, not just 127.0.0.1) for the IP address in the connection string.

Comment: thanks  for your input but i think this will not apply to my case as i said my firewall is turned off ..

Comment: well the database is stored on our server , and we have a static public ip and and we have opened the port in the router and we have set up to Sql Server to listen to that port ,i am afraid that something in the connection string should be wrong .... due to that fact that i could connect from Management Studio to the same IP and port from a computer outside of our network

Comment: Take out the ",12345" .. aka, remove the port #.  See what happens.

Comment: You may need to post the .config section (assuming you're using <connectionStrings> section to hold your value.

Answer (score 0):

to update you all if this issue might happen to you as well .

my website is hosted as shared hosting by hostgator and they claim that for security they will only allow traffic for sql to be done only via port 1433, which is the default port for sql...
hope this helps someone in the future